# Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument

Tags: angular, typescript

Below Angular 2 (TypeScript) code gave me below 3 error, how to resolve them. please suggest.

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
    selector: 'http-client',
    template: `<h1>All Products</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
       {{product.title}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `})
class AppComponent {

    products: Array<string> = [];

    theDataSource: Observable;

    constructor(private http: Http) {

        this.theDataSource = this.http.get('api/products/')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Get the data from the server
        this.theDataSource.subscribe(
            data => {
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    this.products = data;
                } else {
                    this.products.push(data);
                }
            },
            err =>
                console.log("Can't get products. Error code: %s, URL: %s ", err.status, err.url),
            () => console.log('Product(s) are retrieved')
        );
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
        HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Error are,

1. TS2314   Generic type 'Observable' requires 1 type argument(s).
2. TS7006   Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
3. TS7006   Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
theDataSource: Observable<any>;
```

where `any` can (or should be if possible) be a more concrete type that matches the type of the values it is supposed to emit.

Answer (score 8):

If you look in source of Angular Http module you can find method **request** of Http class

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L111

All other methods (get, post, etc. ) wrap this request. Also you can see that request returns an Observable with generic of Response class. Response class is a part of Http module, so your code can be modified to this:

```
import { HttpModule, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
...
theDataSource: Observable<Response>;
```

Or, if you do not need this strong typification you can pass **any** as parameter of generic

```
theDataSource: Observable<any>;
```

But in my opinion - strong typification is better choice.

Answer (score 2):

1) `theDataSource: Observable;` -> `theDataSource: Observable<any>;`

2/3) you can add `"noImplicitAny": false` to your `tsconfig.json`

or change `data =>`  and `err =>` with `(data: any) =>`  and `(err: any) =>`

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here imo is set it up as `theDataSource: Observable<Response>;` because that is in fact the type based on your work in the constructor.  I'd avoid `any` like a plague.

Side note, I know it doesn't help with your property here, but when trying to do this with methods you can do

```
  type MethodPayload<T> = {
    something: string;
    data: T;
  }

  methodName<T>(payload: MethodPayload<T>) {
    // thing with payload
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the issue by command:
npm install @types/googlemaps@3.39.12 --save-dev

Answer (score -2):

Could it be just the missing angle brackets?

`Observable(PhotosResult)` instead of `Observable<PhotosResult>`