# Is there any way to prevent destroying a component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

We know that there is a method ngOnDestroy() in angular which runs on destroying a component but I want to know that is there any way to prevent it from destroying?

Comment: can you explain what exactly you are trying? seems like an XY scenario...

Comment: Can you specify any scenario

Comment: `canDeactivate` router guard

Comment: Does your application use Routing? I think it should. If it does, check https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate this

Comment: It is not very wise to do that bcz it helps in any memory leak issues. If you have anything created and it should not have to be on other routes which is a definite candidate to destroy it in `ngOnDestroy()` like some subscriptions.

Comment: Look into your [RouterReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). It allows Angular to reuse Components that have been routed away from.

Comment: Check out this StackOverflow answer for a detailed code sample. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62409873/4109794

Answer (score 11):

The **CanDeactivate** guard has access to the instance of the active component, so you can implement a *hasChanges()* that check if there have been changes and conditionally ask for the user confirmation before leave.
In the following example the *CanDeactivateComponent* implements the methods *hasChanges()* that returns a boolean value indicating if the components has detected any changes.
The implementation of *CanDeactivate* guard is similar to the *CanActivate* guard implelementaion (you can create a function, or a class that implements the *CanDeactivate* interface):

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { CanDeactivateComponent } from './app/can-deactivate';

export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanDeactivateComponent> 
{
  canDeactivate(target: CanDeactivateComponent) 
  {
    if(target.hasChanges()){
      return window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Even though, this is a very trivial implementation, *CanDeactivate* uses a generic, so you need to specify what component type you want to deactivate.

In the Angular router of the component:

```
{ 
  path: '',
  component: SomeComponent,
  canDeactivate: [ConfirmDeactivateGuard]
}
```

Last, like all other services on Angular, this guard needs to be registered accordingly:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    ConfirmDeactivateGuard
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can have multiple guards protecting a single route, which helps you implementing sophisticated use cases, where a chain of different checks is needed.