# Angular - I need avoid the destroy of the component

Tags: angular, iframe, routes, components, destroy

I have a component with an `<iframe>` element inside.

This component is called for a route.

When the component is called, the `<iframe>` element reloads the content, but I need load this content only once. For this, I will need to cancel the destroy of this component.

I tried moving this `<iframe>` to `<body>` element when the `onDestroy` is called and reuse this when this component is called again, but when you move an `<iframe>` to another parent, his content is reloaded.

Does someone have an idea of how do this?

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514644/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-destroying-a-component-in-angular

Comment: You're not forced to keep your component : what you're forced to keep is your `iframe`. Components that aren't used need to be destroyed. Simply load your iframe in a global variable (or in a service) and fetch it with your component on load.

Comment: @Suryan: The CanDeactivate can´t help me, because I need change the screens when I change the route.

Comment: @trichetriche - I know, but if I change the father of `<iframe>` element, the `<iframe>` will be load again.

Comment: It's not supposed to have a "father" to start with ... Your `iframe` should be created with full JS and stored in a variable, that was my point

Comment: @trichetriche - I understand your point, but when you put the element `<iframe>` inside of a new element, your content will be reload.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? You could use `appendChild` and `removeChild` and keep the variable up, I'm not sure it reloads the frame ... (but I'm far from being an expert on that matter)

Comment: @trichetriche - I'm far from an expert on that matter too kkk .. Well, I'm tested this and the reaction of the component was this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I solved my problem!**

I created a component with `position: fixed`, one level up of `router-outlet` component.

When the user go in of the route, the `ngAfterViewInit` will be call the fixed component to show the `iframe`.

When the user go out of the route, the `OnDestroy` will be call the method to hide the `iframe`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for would be the [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy).

Instead of destroying + re-creating components on consequent visits, you can re-use your routes.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854611/5116121) for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but this strategy dont solve this problem with the iframe element. I tried too.