# Angular rxjs Observer Generic Type required 1 argument

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular8

I am facing following error while using Observers with Observables from rxjs package.

ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(25,57): error TS2314: Generic type 'Observer' requires 1 type argument(s).

I am trying to create my first Observable

```
const myObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer) => {
setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('first package');},2000);
setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('second package');},4000);
setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('this does not work');},5000);
 });
```

Can you suggest, what could be the possible solution ?

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757684/generic-type-observablet-requires-1-type-argument
this link will help you or put some code here, thanks

Comment: use `(observer: Observer<string>) =>` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eldar mentioned in the comment Observer interface expects generic type

```
interface Observer<T> {
  closed?: boolean;
  next: (value: T) => void;
  error: (err: any) => void;
  complete: () => void;
}
```

Change your Observer interface to `Observer<string>`

```
const myObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
   setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('first package');},2000);
   setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('second package');},4000);
   setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('this does not work');},5000);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const myObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
       setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('first package');},2000);
       setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('second package');},4000);
       setTimeout(() =>{observer.next('this does not work');},5000);
});
```